Where is the SAP UI API Samples Code Located
Does anyone know where I can find the SAP UI API samples code? I have installed the SAP Business One Studio (1000.00.170), but I can't find the path for the samples code. I also tried searching on the SAP forum; many experts said it is located in the SAP Business One SDK folder, but I can't find it.
:)
I have tried to search for the samples code inside the SAP Business One SDK folder, but found nothing.

On my installation the UI-API samples are located under
C:\Program Files (x86)\SAP\SAP Business One SDK\Samples\COM UI

Thanks for the answer, but I didn't see any folder named 'SAP BUSINESS ONE SDK' under this file path (C:\Program Files (x86)\SAP).
The only folder name I see is 'SAP Business One Client Agent'.

My guess would be that it's a separate component that you need to find the installer for. Sorry, that's all I've got.

I see. I will try to search for it. Thanks for the help.
